# Print first 20 items in array in reverse, then print the next 20 in reverse, and so on

Tags: java, arrays, printing, reverse

so I'm working on my Java assignment where I'm given a big array.
I'm told to print the first 20 items in the array in reverse order,
then print the next 20 items in reverse order again, and so forth until I reach the end of the array.

I was able to work out how to print the first items in reverse, but then I'm having trouble implementing something that would let me continue where I left from the original array.

I'm also only allowed to have 21 items stored at a time.

Here's what I have so far (50items instead of 20)

```
public static void doIt(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {
    LinkedList<String> s = new LinkedList<String>();
    int counter = 0;
    int max = 50;

    for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line = r.readLine()) {
        if (counter < max) {
            s.addFirst(line);
            counter++;
        }

        if (counter == max) {
            for (String n : s) {
                System.out.println(n);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering if someone can help me out, not sure what I can do from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to print the list whenever `counter` hits a multiple of 20 as well as when it hits `max`. Then, after you print the contents of `s`, clear the list:

```
s.clear();
```

That will remove all elements so it will fill up again. You also need to print the list after the `for` loop exits, otherwise the last few items will be left unprinted.

Note that you are not using an array anywhere in this code. It's not clear that you are following the spirit of the assignment by using a `LinkedList`. But only you know what the rubric is.

Comment: thank you for that simple s.clear();
I was able to fix it and get it done with just that.

Answer (score 0):

For this part of the question:

> I'm told to print the first 20 items in the array in reverse order, then print the next 20 items in reverse order again, and so forth until I reach the end of the array.

One simple solution would be to:

- iterate 20 places in the array
- store this position in a temp index
- iterate back 20 places printing the array
- repeat process from stored temp index

Also, keep in mind if the last print might have less than 20 elements.

```
int size = 20; // size of reversed chunks

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i += size) {
    int j = (i + (size - 1) < array.length) ? (i + size - 1) : array.length - 1;
    for(; j >= i; j--) {
        System.out.print(array[j] + " ");
    }
}
```

However, there is no array in your code so I am not sure what you meant by that. You are reading values from a file and then using a `LinkedList` to print them in reverse. A better, more natural data structure, for printing in reverse (as well as most "reversal" operations) would be a `Stack` although Java's implementation for `LinkedList` is implemented such that it allows for `Stack` (**LIFO**) behavior. It is just generally used as a `Queue` (**FIFO**) structure. My answer will use a `LinkedList` as well to make it consistent with your approach but think about a `Stack` in this situation in the future.

So, since you are reading numbers, line by line from a file, here is what you can do:

- You can read and insert the numbers at the top of a `LinkedList` until you reach the `max` value or the end of file

  *You already have that part working*
- Print all the numbers by removing them from the top of the `LinkedList` which will make them in reverse order

  *You are printing them but not removing them or clearing the list by calling `s.clear()`*
- Once you reach the end of file you could end up with values still in the `LinkedList` because you reached end of file before you reached `max` items and the loop finished but nothing was printed. Print these values as well.

Another thing, it seems like you are not writing to the file so you don't need the `PrintWriter` parameter of the function.

Here is the code:

```
public static void doIt(BufferedReader r) throws IOException {
    LinkedList<String> s = new LinkedList<String>();
    int counter = 0;
    int max = 50;

    for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line = r.readLine()) {
        if (counter < max) {
            s.addFirst(line);
            counter++;
        }

        if (counter == max) {
            while(!s.isEmpty()) { // remove and print in reverse order
                System.out.println(s.removeFirst());
            }
            counter = 0; // reset counter
        }
    }

    // print the remaining elements, if they exist
    while(!s.isEmpty()) { // remove and print in reverse order
            System.out.println(s.removeFirst());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can get you started:

```
void example() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) { //fill array to be read (for this example)
        myArray[i] = i;
    }
    readback();


}

 void readback() {

    int batch = 1; //represents a portion of the read operation
    int batchSize = 20; //the size of the read portion
    int pos = 0; //the current index of the array while it is being read
    int hi; //the top of the batch
    int lo; //the bottom of the batch


    while (pos < myArray.length) {

        if (batch*batchSize<myArray.length) { //make sure you are not going over the array boundary
             hi =  batch*batchSize;
             lo = hi - batchSize;
        } else {
            hi = myArray.length;
            lo = pos;
        }

        for (int i = hi - 1; i >= lo; i--) { //read
            System.out.println(myArray[i]);
            pos++;
        }
        batch++; //go to the next batch
    }

}
```